# What is the right way for Singleton pattern in Typescript/ES6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, singleton

```
class Foo{

}

var instance: Foo;
export function getFooInstance(){
    /* logic */
}
```

or

```
export class Foo{
    private static _instance;
    private constructor(){};
    public getInstance(){/* logic */}
}

// Use it like this
Foo.getInstance()
```

I want to make sure there is only one way instance of the object ? Any other suggestions apart from this ?

Typescript Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20export%20class%20Foo%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20_instance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20constructor()%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getInstance()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!Foo._instance)%20Foo._instance%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Foo._instance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20_instance%3A%20Bar%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20getBarInstance()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!_instance)%20_instance%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20_instance%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A) for both:

Comment: Side note: JavaScript doesn't really permit enforcing limits on instances. Since inheritance is between objects (prototypal) rather than between classes, it's always possible to create a 2nd instance – `var second = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(singleton));`. Though, yes, this is more cumbersome than `new Foo()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use the getter in the class then it needs to be static:

```
export class Foo{
    private static _instance;
    private constructor(){};
    public static getInstance(){/* logic */}
}
```

The thing is that while the compiler will enforce this private visibility, in runtime it will still be possible to bypass it, even unintentionally, if for example someone uses that from javascript directly.

If you enforce it using a module/namespace then you can completely hide it:

Using a module:

```
export interface IFoo {}

class Foo implements IFoo {}

var instance: Foo;
export function getFooInstance(): IFoo {
    /* logic */

    return instance;
}
```

It's your code, I just aded the `IFoo` interface (which is also exported) so that who ever gets an instance will know the interface but not the class.

Using a namespace:

```
namespace Foo {
    export interface IFoo {}

    class FooClass implements IFoo {}

    const instance = new FooClass();
    export function getInstance(): IFoo {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new (getInstance().constructor)()` still creates a new instance, no matter if you're trying to hide the class in a namespace/module.

Answer (score 5):

In JS and therefore TypeScript, if you really just want one instance, why not enforce w/ the language itself, by just exporting an object literal?

```
const Foo = {
  doSomething() {

  }
}

export default Foo;
```

IMO, this is following KISS, least amount of boilerplate and there is no way for anyone to create multiple instances.

That being said you could also just export functions directly. Remember a module itself can serve as singleton for you.

```
export function doSomething() {
}
```

Then importing and wanted to treat it as an object you could use the import *. I prefer the first approach if the functions really belong to the object and are not all stateless static functions.

```
import * as Foo from './Foo';

Foo.doSomething();
```

Comment: If I import Foo multiple times in different files they will all reference the same object?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if there should be an opportunity to create a new instance for singleton class or not. In the last case `getInstance` can be omitted and class constructor may act as singleton factory:

```
class Foo {
    private static _instance;
    constructor(...args) {
        if (Foo._instance) {
            return Foo._instance;
        }

        // if Foo extends non-singleton class or whatever,
        // super(...args);

        Foo._instance = this;
    };
}
```

The same thing can be done with a decorator for any arbitrary class, like:

```
@singleton
class Foo { ... }
```

Due to the fact that there are some [typing problems with TypeScript decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), custom inheritance code should be used inside `singleton` decorator instead of `Singleton extends Class`:

```
function singleton(Class) {
    function extend(sub, sup) {

        for (var prop in sup)
            if (sup.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                sub[prop] = sup[prop];

        function __() {
            this.constructor = sub;
        }

        __.prototype = sup.prototype;
        sub.prototype = new __();
    };

    const Singleton = <any>function (...args) {
        if (Singleton._instance) {
            return Singleton._instance;
        }

        Class.apply(this, args);

        Singleton._instance = this;
    }

    extend(Singleton, Class);

    return Singleton;
}
```

It may hurt typing but the syntax stays neat.